# How to use Halton sequence in Quasi Monte-Carlo integtation

Tags: random, integral-equations, rendering

I am trying to use Halton sequence numbers for MC estimator for rendering equation. At the moment I pass one instance of .Net Random object and get next number every time using same object thought the whole rendering. With Halton I am not clear though about few things:

- Can the sequence of Halton numbers be generated in one dimension(ex. base 2) for sampling the light source triangle or sampling the hemisphere(for the indirect reflection ray)? Or do I need different dimensions for each sampling?
- Does the Russian Roulette condition need a separate sequence of numbers with a different base or can the same sequence be used?
- The same question for super sampling the pixels for anti-aliasing.

Basically what I don't understand is that why N sequences with N different bases are needed for say sampling a N-dimension point(ex. using base 2, 3, 7 for a 3d point x y z)?